# mongoose doesn't fetch updated data, unless nodejs is restarted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose collection called agents. I'm able to see the updated data using mongodb console. But unable to fetch the updated data, using $.ajax or $.get

I'm new to nodejs and mongoose. The data I update, is getting updated on the mongodb database, but not on the client even after a refresh.

The route which sends the updated collection to the client

```
router.get('/:function', function(req, res) {
  if (req.params.function === 'getWeeklyTarget') {
    helper.getWeeklyTarget().then(values => {
      res.send(values);
    })
  }
})
```

The getWeeklyTarget function

```
function getWeeklyTarget() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Find Current Week
        let this_month = `${moment().format('MMMM')} ${moment().format('YYYY')}`;
        let this_week;
        let team_targets = [];

        Month.find({name: this_month})
            .then(foundMonth => {
                foundMonth.forEach(month => {
                    if (month.name === this_month) {
                        this_week = month.current_week;
                    }
                    findTeams.then(foundTeams => {
                        let this_week_target = [];
                        foundTeams.forEach(team => {
                            let counter = 0;
                            let another_counter = 0;
                            team.members.forEach(agent => {
                                if (this_week === 'first_week') {
                                    counter += agent.weekly_target.first_week
                                    another_counter += agent.total_sales
                                }else if (this_week === 'second_week') {
                                    counter += agent.weekly_target.second_week
                                    another_counter += agent.total_sales
                                }else if (this_week === 'third_week') {
                                    counter += agent.weekly_target.third_week
                                    another_counter += agent.total_sales
                                } else if (this_week === 'fourth_week') {
                                    counter += agent.weekly_target.fourth_week
                                    another_counter += agent.total_sales
                                }
                            })
                            this_week_target.push({
                                name: team.name,
                                target: counter,
                                achieved: another_counter
                            })
                        })
                        resolve(this_week_target);
                    })
                })
            })
    }) 
}
```

Once the collection is updated, I want to fetch the updated data to the client

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `resolve()` method is called more than once since it is called inside `forEach` loop. try declaring the `this_week_target` out side the `forEach` loop and call `resolve()` also out side the forEach loop. like this

```
function getWeeklyTarget() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Find Current Week
        let this_month = `${moment().format('MMMM')} ${moment().format('YYYY')}`;
        let this_week;
        let team_targets = [];

        Month.find({name: this_month})
            .then(foundMonth => {
              let this_week_target = [];
                foundMonth.forEach(month => {
                    if (month.name === this_month) {
                        this_week = month.current_week;
                    }
                    findTeams.then(foundTeams => {
                        foundTeams.forEach(team => {
                            let counter = 0;
                            let another_counter = 0;
                            team.members.forEach(agent => {
                                if (this_week === 'first_week') {
                                    counter += agent.weekly_target.first_week
                                    another_counter += agent.total_sales
                                }else if (this_week === 'second_week') {
                                    counter += agent.weekly_target.second_week
                                    another_counter += agent.total_sales
                                }else if (this_week === 'third_week') {
                                    counter += agent.weekly_target.third_week
                                    another_counter += agent.total_sales
                                } else if (this_week === 'fourth_week') {
                                    counter += agent.weekly_target.fourth_week
                                    another_counter += agent.total_sales
                                }
                            })
                            this_week_target.push({
                                name: team.name,
                                target: counter,
                                achieved: another_counter
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
                resolve(this_week_target);
            })
    }) 
}
```

Comment: The issue still prevails. Mongoose Still doesn't return the updated data.